# Avoid cascading actions on PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

Suppose I have this model:

```
public sealed class Model : ModelBase // base is a INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
{        
    private void SomeAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeAction!");
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "A":
                B = A + 1;
                SomeAction();
                break;
            case "B":
                SomeAction();
                break;
        }
    }

    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            if (a != value)
            {
                a = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("A");
            }
        }
    }
    private int a;

    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set
        {
            if (b != value)
            {
                b = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("B");
            }
        }
    }
    private int b;      
}
```

Here is two properties: `A` and `B`. `B` depends from `A` - when value of `A` changes, `B` must be changed too. Anyway, when any of these properties are changed, `SomeAction` should be executed.

Obviously, I want to avoid two calls of `SomeAction` when `A` is changed.
Is there any elegant way to do this (some kind of boolean flag isn't an elegant way)?

**UPD**.

May be, I should mention, that I'm looking for more generic solution, than ones provided in the answers below. The reason is that when the number of properties grows, the code complexity grows more faster. E.g., these graph - `D` <- `C` <- `A` -> `B` - will cause the code, that won't be easy maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `SomeAction` in each property setter:

```
public int A
{
    get { return a; }
    set
    {
        if (a != value)
        {
            a = value;
            b = value + 1;
            OnPropertyChanged("A");
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
            SomeAction();
        }
    }
}
private int a;

public int B
{
    get { return b; }
    set
    {
        if (b != value)
        {
            b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
            SomeAction();
        }
    }
}
private int b;
```

Comment: This will still call `SomeAction` twice because of property setter `B = value + 1;`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yeah, I just noticed and did a rollback.

Comment: This looks decent, +1

Comment: @Henrik: thanks for the answer. The problem is that your code avoids duplicate call of `SomeAction`, but it doesn't solve the task in general. What would you do, if there's 3 or 4 properties, or if the dependency graph would be a little bit more complex?

Answer (score 0):

```
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "A":
            //Change the Private b instead of B so it won't call SomeAction twice.
            b = A + 1;
            SomeAction();
            break;
        case "B":
            SomeAction();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: -1 That's wrong. You've changed the value of `b` and not firing `PropertyChanged` event. Any bounded properties won't update.

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria for whether multiple property changes are to be considered a single action appears to be: "is it handled within the `OnPropertyChanged` method?" But it is also this method that is solely responsible for calling the action in the first place, so... why not just design `OnPropertyChanged` to avoid the cascading? It should be as simple as removing one of the calls:

```
case "A":
    B = A + 1;
    break;
case "B":
    SomeAction();
    break;
```

I don't see that this is inelegant since all the logic is localized to a single method. You basically have a recursive method here where "B" is the terminating condition.